# How to avoid retrieving spring beans from application context in webapp?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans, autowired

I'm designing a webapp and I would prefer not to have to call context.getBean() inside my entry point to the service.

Ideally I would like to @Autowire beans, however this is not working for me.

The JUnit tests are able to see the Autowired beans just fine, but the web application is not.

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:config/spring/serviceContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

**serviceContext.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="service.myservice"/>
```

**ApplicationConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"service.myservicecontrller"})
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Autowired ServiceController controller;
}
```

**MyService.class**

```
@WebService(<snipped this out>)
@BindingType("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/http")
public class MyService extends ServiceBase implements  ApplicationContextAware {

/** The context. */
@Resource
WebServiceContext context;

@Autowired 
ServiceController controller;

public doFeature(...) { return controller.getTimeout();} <----- this is where the NPE is
```

**ServiceController.java**

```
@Component
public class ServiceController {
public int timeout = 100;
public void setTimeout(int t) {
this.timeout = t;
}
public int getTimeout() { return this.timeout; }
public ServiceController(){}
}
```

I don't want to have to get the context and do context.getBean() every time a web request comes in - I was hoping the @Autowire would allow me to access the bean.

I put Spring in Debug and it says the bean is created, so I am not sure what is going on.

I've seen web apps do this using static variables but I don't want to make any of the beans static, so I'm trying to avoid that as well.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**RESOLVED!** After reading the following JIRA I was able to resolve it. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9786

Answer (score 0):

Are your beans annotated with @Component?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added @Component to the configuration class, and the service class. It is on the Controller class already. It didn't seem to do the trick though.

Comment: Another suggestion - though this is probably nothing - is that you have an odd spelling of "service.myservicecontrller" (missing the o). Is that intentional?

Comment: Just that the object is null when I try to invoke it. I changed the names of everything as it's a work project and I didn't want to use the real names of everything due to NDAs and all of that jazz. :)

The JUnit AssertNotNull() works on the object when I create a test and use the following:
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=ApplicationConfig.class)

So it's just down to the way the web app is trying to use the object. I really want to design this in such a way that I don't need to call getBean() on the context but I just can't seem to get it working.

Comment: So, the object is fine when the tomcat server starts up. I can see it being initialized without issue. It's when a web request comes in that the object is null.